# Launch application by dialing a number then disconnect call: Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to launch my application by dialing a number and I got success in doing the same.

I'm performing this action by this code:

```
public class OutgoingCallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    String diledNumber;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        diledNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        if(diledNumber.equals("1234"))
        {
            Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            appIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(appIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
My problem is after launching the application, calling screen is going into background and my application is getting started in front. But I want to disconnect that call (I dialed 1234 to launch application, After app launch that call should get disconnect). Your help will be very appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Use `setResultData(null)` into the if block to cancels the broadcast from your receiver.*

Refer the below code

```
if(diledNumber.equals("1234")) {
     Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
     appIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     context.startActivity(appIntent);
     // Cancel our call.
     setResultData(null);
}
```

Read more about [Processing Ordered Broadcasts](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html)